# Unity 2D, how to know if mouse pointer is moving clockwise or counter clockwise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry, linear-algebra, angle

I'm trying to check if the player is moving the mouse pointer clockwise or counter clockwise but I can't manage to do it. I tried with cross and with signed angle but I think i didn't understand well how to use them, can someone please give a general code example? it would help a lot for understanding.

Comment: To determine CW/CCW you must have also the third (base) point, or sequence of three positions forming arc

Answer (score 0):

I solved by doing the Vector cross of the previous mouse position direction and the current mouse position direction, here's the code

```
 private void Update()
{
    Vector3 dirPre = (lastTouchPos - transform.position);
    Vector3 dirPost = (myCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position);
    dirPre.z = 0;
    dirPost.z = 0;

    //IF CURRENT MOUSE IS CLOCKWISE IT THE VECTOR CROSS Z AXIS WILL BE POSITIVE OTHERWISE IT WILL BE NEGATIVE
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.Cross(dirPre, dirPost) * 10, Color.red, Time.deltaTime);
    lastTouchPos = myCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}
```